# AS3 - simpleStageVideo smoothing

Tags: actionscript-3, smoothing

I'm using a simpleStageVideo for playing FLV movies. All is fine, but when size changing, the video is not smoothing. So, how can i apply smoothing with using this class? 
When i trying:

`ss.video.smoothing = true;//ss - simpleStageVideo`

there is no effect :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really familiar with SimpleStaveVideo but if I remember correctly (assuming it is the class of Thibault Imbert):

`ss.video` => returns a video instance, NOT a stage video instance; That's why you can apply smoothing to it (otherwise you would get an error, there is no smoothing property on StageVideo).

For StageVideo it should be enough to set the viewPort correctly, how exactly are you resizing? Are you calling `ss.resize(w, h)`?

Answer (score 0):

Like Fygo said you cannot "smooth" stageVideo. If it's the regular Video object you are trying to smooth and you're using the code as found here: [[ Code.Google link ]](https://code.google.com/p/simplestagevideo/source/browse/trunk/SimpleStageVideo/src/org/bytearray/video/SimpleStageVideo.as?spec=svn22&r=22)

You can try:

```
ss._video.smoothing = true;
```

If you look at the simpleStageVideo.as you will see these lines..

```
private var _video:Video;
private var _sv:StageVideo;
```

That's how you can access and edit properties of those items from your own Class without having to manually edit simpleStageVideo.as itself --- Or else just add the smoothing line within simpleStageVideo.as by looking for the function where it switches to use   `_video`   and add smoothing there (under where it attaches NS)

With that said, also make sure your video is not too low-res so that even `smoothing` cannot help with pixelation.

Also check this: [Adobe article link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSe9ecd9e6b89aefd2-68d5ef8f12cc8511f6c-7ffe.html)